# Using std::future with asio::async_connect

Tags: c++, boost-asio, future, asio

I am using the `asio` library and I am trying to connect to a socket.
Sometimes, the socket may take a very long time to connect. In that case, i just want to cancel the connection.

I am attempting to use `std::future` and `asio::use_future` with
**asynchronous operations** to do that. My idea is that i will call the `asio::ip::tcp::socket`'s member function `async_connect()` with `asio::use_future()` and then the `wait_for()` to wait for the `std::future` and check if it is ready or timed out.

If it is timed out I will cancel (return false) and if it is ready, I will continue the work. However, if I attempt to use `wait_for()` and wait for the operation it will never be ready (it almost seems as if it is never run, but not sure how to verify that). Running the same code without using the `std::future` seems to work fine, but I won't be able to enforce a timeout.

This is the code I tried.

```
asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address(peer.address, ec), peer.port);

        if (ec)
        {
            std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        asio::io_context context;

        asio::ip::tcp::socket socket{context};

        std::chrono::milliseconds span(100);

        std::future<void> connect_status = socket.async_connect(endpoint, asio::use_future);

        if (connect_status.wait_for(span) == std::future_status::timeout)
            return false;

        connect_status.get();
```

Comment: Your `io_context` isn't running so no asynchronous processing will happen. See http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_10_6/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/futures/daytime_client.cpp for an example

Comment: If I run the context before the wait_for, it blocks, if I do it after, then I can't tell if it times out or not. The example they use doesn't have a wait_for, which is why I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: you'll need to run it in a thread, see the example

Answer (score 1):

The `asio::io_context` is responsible for performing any asynchronous work. In order for it to do that you must run `context.run()`.

For example see: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/futures/daytime_client.cpp.

The fixed version of your code would be:

```
asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address(peer.address, ec), peer.port);

if (ec)
{
    std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
    return false;
}

asio::io_context context;
auto work = boost::asio::make_work_guard(context);
std::thread thread([&context](){ context.run(); });

asio::ip::tcp::socket socket{context};

std::chrono::milliseconds span(100);

std::future<void> connect_status = socket.async_connect(endpoint, asio::use_future);

if (connect_status.wait_for(span) == std::future_status::timeout)
    return false;

connect_status.get();
```

Comment: True, though I'd probably simplify this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e9444fa2b56e6d0 - of course with c++20 I'd suggest coroutines (something like this https://compiler-explorer.com/z/M6afavnM5)

Comment: @sehe I went with your solution since it seemed the shortest. It works mostly but I occasionally get seg faults. I narrowed it down to happen between two lines of code. My code is here: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/xozWfdjhT it seems between checkpoint 3 and 4 a segfault occurs. Do you have any idea what would cause that or if there is any fault in my logic?

Comment: @ILutRf7 you should ask a new question if you have a new problem. Note that `std::move(std::make_shared` is just weird (but not related to your problem). Looks like you have an unhandled exception, that's not unexpected, you need to catch and handle exceptions

Comment: Sure thing. I asked a new question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056039/segfault-on-async-boost-asio-with-use-future), but for your response, I am wrapping the entire method with a try-catch block in my actual code. Would this not avoid the unhandled exception? Also my understanding is that segfault is different from uncaught exception.